# Detail of a PDF size?

Tags: pdf, latex

I am building a PDF from LaTeX and my document is too big, about 5 MiB. Is there a way to explore the PDF content like "folder sizes" to list what takes space in it?

Comment: Most probably this is due to the images you include. If  you reduce their file size also the file size of the resulting pdf will be smaller.

Comment: There are tools that can do that, Adobe Acrobat for example contains a "Space audit" feature (well hidden) that shows you an overview. But if you post an example PDF document, someone should be able to take a look.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche here a sample https://github.com/heig-tin-info/handout/releases/tag/v0.3.0

Comment: (5 MB is actually surprisingly small for the number of included images...)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes but most of them are vector images, and all the others don’t exceed 1.5MB. So 3MB just for the text and the vectors... it’s too much

Comment: I think you're searching problems where they don't exist. 5Mb for this PDF file is nothing. and it will be very hard to further optimise without quality loss. My advice would be to let it go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [David van Driessche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1682924/david-van-driessche) said, Adobe Acrobat features a Space Audit in the PDF Optimizer module. You'll get this kind of information:

[image]

In your case the `Content Streams` (1.1 MB) and the `X Object Forms` (662 KB) could be optimized somehow... According to [this](https://groups.google.com/g/usc.list.pdf-l/c/5Q7oKM20U2U) conversation X Objects could be the vector images you have.

Comment: There is not much that can be done here to be honest. The PDF is reasonably compressed already, the images take up 45% of the file size, but they don't have a very high resolution. The only area where you could save some space is by cleaning up the fonts, but this would be technically difficult and dangerous and it's only 10% of the file which you might get down to 5% or so. Looking at this numbers I think optimisation is a waste of time unless you're making something where a Mb is a horrible thing.